# Perform multiple face transform using individual axis

Tags: normals

in edit mode, i select 4 faces (image1) and i want to scale them using their own individual normal axis so i can get the result as in image2. How can i do this without manually do it one by one ? is it possible ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Change the Pivot center to individual origins, and change the transformation orientation to normal. If you press <kbd>S</kbd> for scale and <kbd>X</kbd> ***twice*** then you are able to do the transformation
[image]

Comment: No need to select "Normal" as pressing `X` twice automatically goes from global to normal. The Dropdown (2nd red circle in your screenshot) only helps when using the gizmo arrows. Individual origins however is needed.

Comment: Okay? isn't double pressing x,y,z switching from global to local? anyway this was the only way I could make it working:)

Comment: I tested in 2.79 and it toggles between local and global.